# HTML Form Help needed

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have this code what i want is that to reset form once someone click submit button and i want to use html only.

```
<form action="https://examples.webscript.io/attachments/file"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="abc@hotmail.com" readonly> 
    Attached File: input type="file" name="attachment" /><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: add 4 spaces at the beginning so it doesn't change your code to text no need to remove "<"

Comment: use markdown to format your code. Start each code line with 4 spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset form"? There is only a hidden input in your form.

Comment: The input's type attribute value can be `reset`, which means that if you click it, all the inputs would not have value.

Comment: please change Attached File: input to Attached File : <input, you forgot the "<"

Comment: I want once user click submit button, the form sent to the email and attachment gets empty again. and display a "Your Document has submitted". Thanks to y'all for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is using javascript. Change you submit button to:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.form.reset(); this.form.submit();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I was about to post something very similar to that; the JavaScript you mention is built into the form element, instead of being a separate block of script elsewhere in the overall document.  But I do think you have your reset() and your submit() backward; the person asking the question wants to submit the data and THEN reset the form!

Comment: I want once user click submit button, the form sent to the email and attachment gets empty again. and display a "Your Document has submitted".

Thanks to y'all for your help